# GDBus : Migrating to GDBUS and understanding the GVariants and GTypes

Tags: gnome, glib

`GVariant` is opaque data structure used in the `GDBUS` bindings for `libDBus`.

Its been mentioned that `GVariant` is a floating reference count system.  What actually does a floating reference mean in this respect? Also, it is mentioned that the `GVariant` on calling `g_variant_ref_sink()` convert the floating reference into full reference.

May anyone explain what does this mean?

Comment: What is it that you didn't understand.

Comment: Actually i am not clear what is floating reference count. Can you explain me the same.

Answer (score 2):

The [GObject documentation on floating references](https://developer.gnome.org/gobject/stable/gobject-The-Base-Object-Type.html#floating-ref) explains the concept.  GVariant can't depend on GObject (it would be a circular dependency since gobject depends on glib and GVariant is part of glib), so it's not the same implementation, but it is the same concept.

Comment: Thank you. Its explained very well in your above given link.